# In google cloud shell, is it possible to transfer storage buckets to a remote server?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I want to use google cloud shell to transfer buckets (starting in `gs://`) to a remote server. I tried:

scp gsutil gs://folder username@remoteserveraddress:~/folder

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `sshfs` to mount the remote server directory into google cloud shell and then `gsutil cp` as usual in the mountpoint:

```
$ sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@IP_ADDRESS:/mount/share mountpoint
```